# Trouble going through Linked List and deleting duplicate item. (it works in the beginning)

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list

When you receive a number, you need to look through the list and find if this number is duplicated in the list. In case of duplication, delete the number from the list and prepend the new number in the front of the list. If there is no duplication, prepend the number to the list.

This is the correct output:
[Output of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRr8b.png)

This is my LinkedList Class

```
T`public class LinkedList 
{
Node first;
private boolean flag = true;

public void add(int item) 
{
    Node oldFirst = first;
    first = new Node();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldFirst;
    
    removeDuplicate(item);
}

public void show()
{
    for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next) 
    {
        System.out.print(curr.item + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public int listSize()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next) 
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public void removeDuplicate(int item) 
{
    Node prev = first;

    for (Node current = prev.next; current != null && flag; current = 
    current.next)
    {
        if(current.item == item)
        {
            flag = false;
            prev.next = current.next;
        }
        prev = prev.next;      
    }
}

private class Node
{
    int item;
    Node next;
}
}
```

This is my Client

```
    public class ListNoDuplation 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    LinkedList a = new LinkedList();
    
    // Insert: 12
    a.add(12);
    a.show();
    
    // Insert: 13
    a.add(13);
    a.show();
    
    // Insert: 14
    a.add(14);
    a.show();
    
    // Insert: 12
    a.add(12);
    a.show();
    
    // Insert: 10
    a.add(10);
    a.show();
    
    // Insert: 14
    a.add(14);
    a.show();
    
    // Insert: 12
    a.add(12);
    a.show();
    
    // Insert: 15
    a.add(15);
    a.show();
    
    // Insert: 12
    a.add(12);
    a.show();
    
    // Insert: 13
    a.add(13);
    a.show();
    
    System.out.println("List size is: " + a.listSize());
    }
}
```

Then this is the output:

12

13 12

14 13 12

12 14 13

10 12 14 13

14 10 12 14 13

12 14 10 12 14 13

15 12 14 10 12 14 13

12 15 12 14 10 12 14 13

13 12 15 12 14 10 12 14 13

List size is: 9

I can't figure out why it stops working..

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you remove an element, you set your `flag=false`, but never set it to `true` again. That means, after removing the first element during the life cycle of your LinkedList, the flag remains set to `false`.

```
for (Node current = prev.next; current != null; current = current.next)
{
    if(current.item == item)
    {
        prev.next = current.next;
        break; // the `break` keyword provides a much cleaner way to exit your for-loop.
    }
    prev = prev.next;      
}
```

Sidenode: A flag named flag is bad practice, because you never now what that flag signals. And if it's only used inside a Method / Loop, then define it not at class level but at level of said method or loop.

Sidenode 2: In your current implementation as well as with using `break` you will not be able to remove more than one duplicate from the list.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. I really like the versatility of the "break" statement, but I don't understand why my CS professor insists on not using it. When I ask, all he says is that it's "bad practice" which I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `removeDuplicate` method. Your current method implementation is not correct and clear.

- Your current flag value set false once, remains false always. it the main bug.

Suggesation:

- You do not need flag value.
- During the check, set curr = first.next, as always you add a new item first and then remove duplicate. So, the first item check is unnecessary.
- Inside if statement check if you again find item, it find one then remove and break loop. As it is impossible more then one dupilcate value exist.

```
public void removeDuplicate(int item) {
    Node curr = first.next;
    Node prev = first;
    while( curr != null) {
        if(curr.item == item ) {
            prev.next = curr.next;
            break;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Md. Kaswer said right as it is impossible to have a duplicate count greater than 1 and the above solution will work perfectly.